# Регистрационная форма на ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Необходимо сделать регистрационную форму, которая будет отправлять данные по url и получать ответ от сервера в виде ошибки или наоборот успеха в регистрации в формате .json. Необходимо сделать на js, не на jquery. Серверную часть(если так можно назвать) сделал с использованием node js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.', {
  cache: 0
});


function accept(req, res) {

  if (req.url == 'http://blabla/reg') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      file.serve(req, res);
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    file.serve(req, res);
  }
}

// ------ run server -------

if (!module.parent) {
  http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
} else {
  exports.accept = accept;
}v
```

Собственно код js:

```
'use strict';

//Enable || Disable button
var checker = document.getElementById('checker');
checker.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('sent').disabled = !this.checked;
};


//Loading data from form to server
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'http://blabla/registrati', false);

xhr.send([body]);

if(xhr.status != 200) {
    alert('Error ', xhr.status + '' + xhr.statusText);
} else {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Код страницы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign Up form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class = "signUp">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <form name = "sign" method = "POST" action = "#">
            <p class = "username">

                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
            </p>

            <p class = "username">

                <input type="text" name="secondName" placeholder="Second Name" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
            </p>

            <p class = "email">

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" pattern="^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$">
            </p>

            <p class = "gender">
                <select name = "gender[]" required="required">
                    <option value = "male">Male</option>
                    <option value = "female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p class = "password">

                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
            </p>

            <p class = "checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" id = "checker">
                <span>Conditions of Agreement</span>

            </p>

            <p class = "submit">
                    <input type="submit" id = "sent" name = "Sent" disabled="true" onclick = "loadData()">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src = "js/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Делаю это впервые. Я не совсем понял что должно передаваться в url. Адрес сервера или форма, или вывод..просьба помочь, благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример отправки на сервер и Ajax. Используется метод 'POST'.

```js
function sendForm(oFormElement) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
   if(xhr.responseText == userCreated) {
    location.href = "someurl.html";
   } else if (xhr.responseText == createUserError) {
    alert('Input new email. ');
   } else if (xhr.responseText == routeError) {
    alert('Wrong route.');
   }

  }
 };
 xhr.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
 xhr.send (new FormData (oFormElement));

 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Для отправки post запроса , нужно указать заголовок 
   Xhr.setHeader ();
2. Что за ужас в server js.
3. Чтобы принимать заголовки на стороне нода нужен body-parser

Comment: Function (req, res)  { let name = req.body.name }  так же предварительно используйте в middleware сам боди парсер. App.use(bodyParser());

Comment: Я уже сделал, вопрос устарел. Все равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, если ты решил сам то можешь либо опубликовать свой собственный ответ, либо удалить вопрос